# Trying to iterate over if..else but numbers aren't adding up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to iterate over this if else statement as many times as someone wants. If the score = counter wins should get +1 each time, same with losses. However every time it goes through this wins and losses will only stay at 1.

```
var wins1 = 0;
var losses1 = 0;

if(counter == numberToguess)
{
    counter = 0
    console.log("you win")
    randfunction()
    randNum();
    $(".scoreDiv").text(numberToguess)
    losses1 += 1 
    console.log(wins1)       
} else if(counter > numberToguess)
{
    counter = 0
    console.log("you lose")
    randfunction()
    randNum()
    $(".scoreDiv").text(numberToguess)
    losses1 += 1 
    console.log(losses1)
}
```

Comment: well you do not increment wins1, second, looks like you keep resetting wins and losses to zero.

Comment: Also you're re-initialising wins1 and losses1 to 0 so how are they supposed to be anything more than 0 or 1?

Comment: after seen this type of question i feel happy

Comment: May help if you show us the entire loop so we can see how you're iterating

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that reproduces the issue you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the context, but are you declaring `win1` and `losses1` at the top of your loop? If so then they are going to reset to `0` every time the loop runs, hence the final result of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to post what you are using to populate numberToguess so that we can help you finish the script. Ill assume your using a prompt window:

```
var possibilities = 3;
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var answer = "";

while(answer = prompt("guess a number")) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibilities) + 1;
    if(answer == randomNumber) {
        wins++;
        console.log("You Win");
    } else {
        losses++;
        console.log("You Lose");
    }
    console.log("wins: " + wins + " - losses: " + losses);
}
```